# How to track conversions with existing Google Analytics data?

Tags: google-analytics

I just set up my first "Goal" which mark purchases and it's not showing any yet, although I have had 50 purchases since installing Google Analytics.

Is there any way to filter existing data? I want to know the referrer for my past purchases?

I do have the points logged where a purchase was made.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, goals are only forward looking.

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/google-analytics-goals-retroactive-63291.html

Answer (score 1):

The goals set up won't show back-dated stats, however, you can add a secondary dimension of source / medium or of Campaign if you used utm tags to see what source drove those conversions